# Looking to loop a macro that I recorded, skipping rows and ending based on a condition

Tags: vba, macros

Apologies for the uninformed question but I've been looking into macros all morning to help me with a task I'm completing and I haven't found the answers that I need by searching google. I'm using windows 10 and excel 2016. Here's the macro I recorded:

```
Sub biweekly()
'
' biweekly Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+w
'
    Rows("53:53").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("A52:C52").Select
    Selection.Cut Destination:=Range("A53:C53")
    Range("M52").Select
    Selection.Cut Destination:=Range("M53")
    Range("D53").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-2]C+R[-1]C"
    Range("D53").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("E53:L53").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("D53:L53").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Rows("51:52").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Range("A54").Select
End Sub
```

Essentially, I'm combining weekly rows into biweekly rows. I've done this before using pivot tables and getpivotdata but I was hoping for a more elegant solution this time. I would like the macro to loop once it's finished, moving down 3 rows to work on the next pair of weeks afterward (so, in this example, if the new row I created is now row 51 after deleting the individual weekly rows, I would like to move down to row 54 and insert a new row above it to begin working on the week row pairs of 52 and 53).

I don't know how to loop the macro so that it jumps down rows in each loop. I also would like to make a macro stop running conditionally, like when the value in column A changes (I have a large worksheet sorted alphabetically with names containing years of biweekly pay data, and I would like the macro to stop at the end of each name so that I can adjust the pay period concatenation and run it again for the new name). Alternatively, knowing how to make it run a certain number of times (say, 30) would be a good alternative.

Any help at all on any of these issues would be greatly appreciated. Again, apologies for being unfamiliar with macros and VBE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some help with loops is at [How To Repeat Tasks With Your VBA Code by Looping](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2015/4/9/repeat-tasks-with-vba-code-by-looping). The simplest kind of loop would be `For i = 1 to 30` at the beginning and `Next i` at the end.

For your other questions, try the [Offset](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.offset) property:

- To select a cell that is three rows below the current cell, 
   `Selection.Offset(3, 0).Select`
- To stop the macro if a cell is different than the cell three rows above, 
   `If Selection.Value <> Selection.Offset(-3, 0).Value Then Exit Sub`

Recording a macro is a great start. When you become more familiar with VBA code, you will probably merge lines that end with `.Select` and begin with `Selection.`.